# Add "product" to the end of an array "result"

Tags: java, arrays, automated-tests

I'm trying to make a method that returns an array of all found products. I'm a beginner in Java, so I've been thinking for hours and can't understand this.

[image: Check 16th line]

Here is the code and the screenshot of what I've tried and the result:

```java
public class ProductManager {
    private ProductRepository repo;

    public ProductManager(ProductRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public void add(Product product) {
        repo.save(product);
    }

    public Product[] searchBy(String text) {
        Product[] result = new Product[0];
        for (Product product : repo.findAll()) {
            if (matches(product, text)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length ; i++)
                    result[result.length - 1] = product;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean matches(Product product, String search) {
        if (product.getName().contains(search)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In `shouldFindProducts()` method the test **fails** with:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array lengths differ, expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

My **TestClass**:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ProductManagerTest {

    ProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();
    ProductManager manager = new ProductManager(repo);

    Product product1 = new Product(1, "футболка", 550);
    Product product2 = new Product(2, "весна", 480);
    Product product3 = new Product(45, "iphone 12", 34800);

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        manager.add(product1);
        manager.add(product2);
        manager.add(product3);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindProducts() {

        manager.matches(product2, "весна");

        Product[] expected = {product2};
        Product[] actual = manager.searchBy("весна");

        Assertions.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: It's my first post here ever. How can I make it better? Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: My comment *tells* you how

Comment: Changed it a bit. Is it better?

Comment: @Viktor: yes, better, but the test is still just in screenshot form. [This post explains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/40342) why that's bad.

Comment: As to your question: arrays can't be resized and you start with size 0. So you need to copy everything into a new array when you find another hit (or start with a "too big" one and resize down at the end of the method or use an `ArrayList` during the method and convert to an array at the end).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer For now, I know that in "searchBy" I should add some code in if { ... }, but my newbie java brain can't think of an idea, what to write haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the searchBy() method should be implemented with an ArrayList. Notice the method still returns an array by calling the toArray() method on the ArrayList object at the end. But the toArray() method returns an array of Object so you must cast it to Product, that is what the (Product[]) before the result.toArray() does.

Don't for get to import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public Product[] searchBy() {
ArrayList<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product product : repo.findAll()) {
        if (matches(product, text)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length ; i++)
                result.add(product);
        }
    }
    return (Product[])result.toArray();
}
```